# The goal is to eleminate an error message The error Message which appears is "TypeError Methode "clear" von null kann nicht aufgerufen werden."

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an other identical code for a different evaluation where everything works like a charm. With this one I get always the error code 
"TypeError Method "clear" von null kann nicht aufgerufen werden."
Please does anyone have an idea how to solve the issue?
The goal of the script is to combine the data of different spreadsheets into one new so that it is possible to filter that spreadsheet for information.

```
function alle2Daten(){
var sheet1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Zusammenfassung VA November")
sheet1.clear();
// Funktioniert nur wenn Daten in der Tabelle enthalten sind.
var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("04.11.19");
var sheet3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("05.11.19");
sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),sheet2.getLastColumn()).copyTo(sheet1.getRange(1,1));
sheet3.getRange(1,1,sheet3.getLastRow(),sheet3.getLastColumn()).copyTo(sheet3.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow()+2,1));
//sheet1.sort(1);
}
```

Comment: Check the name for your sheet1. Looks like it is not being found. Also, in future please try to provide a translation for non-English error messages.

Comment: `sheet1.clear();` The error message indicates that `sheet1` is null - i.e. it doesn't exist. check the **exact** spelling of your sheet name

Comment: Thank you problem soved it was indeed the spelling there was an empty line in front of the sheet name.